# jQuery onchange event fires twice in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, onchange

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#test').bind("change", function()
            {
                alert(this.value);
                this.value = jQuery.trim(this.value);
            });
        });

    </script>

    <input type="text" id="test" />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" />
</body>
</html>
```

In IE8 if i enter any text to "test" input and press "Tab" I'll get alert message twice.

But if I comment line "this.value = jQuery.trim(this.value);" the message will be shown only once.

Why this happened? And how I can avoid twice "onchange" handler invoking?

Answer (score 3):

The [Issue](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6593) has been reported in jQuery and it has been fixed with the latest code base. 
That was reported on jQuery 1.4 - 1.6.4.

Answer (score 2):

When you set the `value` property of a form element to a different value, the `change` event fires.

So, in your code:

```
$('#test').change(function() {
    // This is executed whenever the `change` event fires
    // Setting a new value will trigger the `change` event again
    this.value = $.trim(this.value);
});
```

By the way, you probably want to use [the `input` event](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/oninput) instead of `change`. There’s a jQuery plugin for that: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery.oninput.js

Comment: But in Chrome 13, FF4 onchange event fires only once.

Comment: @vasmt That’s cross-browser scripting for ya!